# How to keep pulse audio server running after graphical login

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, pulse-audio

I have a laptop (ubuntu 14.04) connected to my stereo, acting as a pulseaudio server. If I just boot that laptop, I can play sound from other laptops with no problem. But if I then log into my gnome desktop, the playback stops. I can play music on the gnome desktop now, but the previously running music is stopped. How can I configure the pulseaudio server to keep running even after logging in?

I tried to run it in daemon mode

```
#grep daemonize /etc/pulse/daemon.conf
daemonize = yes
```

and also tried to disable

```
chmod -x /usr/bin/start-pulseaudio-x11
```

with no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing is to have **no** pulseaudio at all as an individual user. To do that,

```
    mkdir $HOME/.pulse
    cp /etc/pulse/client.conf $HOME/.pulse
```

and now, in the file just created, change

```
     autospawn=yes
```

into

```
     autospawn=no
```

Log out, log back in, it should be fine. If it is not, reboot.

For any problem with the cumbersome `pulse-audio`, I suggest you read the ever informative [Arch Linux wiki entry](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples).

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, unfortunatly is did not work. I did as instructed, rebooted, but when I log in, the audio stops.